# Embedding  commutative  associative  rings  in  non  associative   rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let  $R$  be  a  commutative  and  associative  ring  with  unit. Can $R$  be  embedded  in  a  ring  $\hat{R}$  wich  is  both  non  commutative and  non associative ?

Thanks  guys !

Comment: What do you mean by a nonassociative ring?

Comment: And what do you mean by embedded?  If I say that a ring $A$ is embedded in another ring $B$, I mean that there is an injective ring homomorphism from $A$ to $B$.  What kind of morphism do you want from your associative ring to your nonassociative "ring"? 

Comment: I posted very similar comments, but then deleted them when I realized there is a wikipedia article on nonassociative rings, and it's the first hit from a google search. The second question is harder to answer...I don't know what subobjects are for these so-called non-associative rings.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  The "can" question is not so interesting:  think of the image of the integers inside any nonassociative algebra.  But specific cases, and counting embeddings, are interesting.  See work of Gross and Gan, "[Commutative Subrings of Certain Non-associative Rings](http://www.springerlink.com/content/9c6mqcxn5j2cvcfd/)", Math. Ann. v.314 n.2, 1998.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/s002080050294](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002080050294 "zbMATH review at https://zbmath.org/0990.11018").